# How to avoid READ_PHONE_STATE Android permission

Tags: codenameone

Is there a way of not include android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE in manifest, when I need to obtain unique device identifier and need to use push messages? In Germany (and corporate apps targeted for German market) there are legal issues, that forbids that permission to be used (it's kind of a strong permission, if an app is asking user, if it can read the phone state).

Simply, how can I 1.) use push messages 2.) get unique device id without having that permission in manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the device identifier for push, you just need the push key in which case `getDeviceId()` or similar calls are never made. If you follow the [push tutorial](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---use-push-notification-send-server-push-messages.html) there won't be any permission for phone state within your app.

Comment: ok, when I removed the call of `Display.getInstance().getUdid()`, the permission is no longer needed, thanx